# FloatLeft not working when text starts to wrap

Tags: css

Looking for some help here please. I am having an issue with a table I have created pulling info from our DB. I have the two columns floating the data to the left when displayed and it works fine.... Unless the data is longer than one line and wraps it then floats it in the center for some reason.

Below is the code.

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="mainTable">
   <tbody>
     <tr>
        <th class="w12p"><span class="marginLft05 css3 floatLeft">Type</span></th>
        <th class="w20p"><span class="marginLft05 css3 floatLeft">Detail</span></th>
     </tr>
<?
foreach($product_specifications as $key => $specification):
?>
      <tr class="<?=iif($key % 2 == 0, 'lightSpecRow', 'darkSpecRow')?>">
   <td>
       <span class="marginLft05 font14 css3 floatLeft"><?=$specification['name']?></span>
   </td>
   <td>
       <span class="marginLft05 font14 css3 floatLeft"><?=$specification['value']?></span>
   </td>
</tr>
<?
endforeach;
?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Issue is with the

```
<td>
<span class="marginLft05 font14 css3 floatLeft"><?=$specification['value']?></span>
</td>
```

Any and all help is appreciated, thanks!

Thanks everyone, after all the comments and suggestions it got me thinking in a different direction and I found a way to get it to work with a change in the table class.

by adding a float left in the table class definition it seemed to work on all browsers

Comment: Where is the `CSS` definition of the class `floatleft`? That class could have anything in it, and diagnosing your problem is impossible without it.

Comment: Why don't you use `<th align="left">Content</th>`?

Comment: I made an example to try to diagnose your problem, feel free to use it and add to it.  http://jsbin.com/zarar/1/

Comment: .floatRight { float: right !important; }
    .floatLeft { float: left !important; }

Comment: @Harvey that worked for Chrome but FF and IE no change.

Comment: add css to it and you can see it not working http://jsbin.com/zarar/6/edit

Comment: @user2465180 If you pull out your extra wrapping and use CSS `th { text-align: left; }` things behave normally. See http://jsbin.com/zarar/8/edit

Comment: Looked a link it is still showing the same. First row short looks good last to are too long and are centered. forgot to mention you keep talking about th it is the lower td that has the issue really.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined TD alignment to center in class `.mainTable tr td`.

You should remove this attribute and remove `floatLeft` class (no need this class once you remove center text-alignment).

By removing this attribute, will be considered `text-align: left` by default.

Updated jsbin: http://jsbin.com/zarar/13/